# retain object value of each user ruby on rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I have developed two rest API for my android app in ROR. The idea is, when user clicks to get last '24' hour data, my api return the data from last 24 hours.

but in addition, after this query I use the received object of 24 hours in new Rest API call method called as SHOW for some other filtering.

here is my code

```
def index
    json = Hash.new
    if not ReturnbackHelper.check(params)
        render :status => :unauthorized, :json => "unauthorized"
        return
    end
    @r = ReturnHelper.filter(params)
    if(params[:selector] == '24')
        json = ReturnTimeHelper.tffilter(params, @r)
    else
        json = ReturnTimeHelper.otherfilter(params, @r)
    end
    puts json.to_json
    render :status => :ok, :json => json
end                                                                                          


def show                                                                                                
    if (params[:selector] == '24')
        @s = ReturnDiaHelper.tffilter(params, @r)
    else
        @s = ReturnDiaHelper.otherfilter(params, @rs)
    end
    render :status => :ok, :json => @s
end
```

So the problem is when user query for 24 hour data which I am using in show method as well, it work fine but if other user query for the 24 hour data then the object for the last user also get updated with new one with the data of new user. 
so how can i retain the object per user and destroy it once new query is made..

I am new in ruby, so any pointer to fix it. I hope i am clear

Answer (score 0):

You are using class variable `@@r`, so whenever a use is making request its getting updated.
use instance variable `@r` and it would work.
Also read diff b/w instance variable and class variable in ruby and there uses.

Comment: I am trying with instance variable , getting it null, I guess somwwhere I am initialisationg it

Comment: First of all you are using @rs in show but not decleared/intialized it so it will return nil.second you are using @r same variable for every user that is why its getting overrided.you should use some kind of dynamic way to declare instance varible so in show action you can get it for different objects sepratly.for ex. use username, it will be uniq and in your show action you can get it like username etc.

Comment: thanks, @rs is typo it is correct it code, but can you give me  bit cleaner example...I got the point..but clean example would be good thanks